# Java: Difference between these two wrapper class statements

Tags: java, wrapper

I'm a newbie to programming. Tell me the difference between 
`Integer x= 59;` and `Integer x= new Integer (59);`
They both do the same thing basically and I'm getting the output either way.

```
public class WrapperClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Integer x= 59; // 
        byte y= x.byteValue();
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class WrapperClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Integer x = new Integer (10);
        byte y= x.byteValue();
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: see : http://www.javatpoint.com/wrapper-class-in-java

Answer (score 6):

Not much difference. Autoboxing ( `Integer x = 59;`) will call `Integer.valueOf( 59 );` while the other method calls the constructor. Has minor implications for caching (valueOf might give the same object reference for two equal values, new will not), but not much more.

And just to make sure: Autoboxing/`valueOf` MIGHT give you the same object reference when calling it two times with two equal values (at least if your values are between -128 an 127), but that still makes it a very, very bad idea to compare two Integer objects via `==`.